# Build similar Windows Phone 7 animated buttons

Tags: silverlight

Does anyone know a tutorial an how the buttons from the main screen of the Windows Phone 7 were build in Silverlight ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `HubTile` control from the [wp7 toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550). It might be what you are looking for. :)